# Retrieve geometry from GeoJSON to L.polygon in Leaflet?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

Since I have a problem with Leaflet draw, which, unfortunately is discontinued, I'm trying to rely on Leaflet editable for editing: before I learn how to save edits, I just want to retrieve a polygon from my database as a L.polygon that Leaflet editable can read.

About the code: this is Leaflet CRUD, available on github, modified, relying on Leaflet draw.

This is the state of the code: the data is read through the AJAX call and is retrieved as geojson or featuregroup... but is not passing to the L.polygon. leaflet editable is reading only l.polygon , not featuregroup, not featurelayer, so I'm trying to translate. That's what I would like to achieve:

```
function _displayMapEditPolygon(divtarget, objectgid) {
objectsGroup.clearLayers();
    /* Digitize Function */
    drawnItems_editpolygon = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems_editpolygon);

    var promiseObjectEdit = $.ajax({
        url: "../crud/dataservice/read_one_polygon.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            command: "POLYGON",
            gid: objectgid,
            current_file: current_file
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        username: null,
        password: null,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('i asked the response');
    },
    });


promiseObjectEdit.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);


    L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: _onEachFeature_editpolygon
    });
});
    function _onEachFeature_editpolygon(feature, layer) {
        drawnItems_editpolygon.addLayer(layer);
console.log(data);
for ( var i=0; i < layer.features.length; i++ ) {
    feat = layer.features[i];coords = [];
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < feat.geometry.coordinates[0].length - 1; j++ ) {
        coord = feat.geometry.coordinates[0][j];point = [];
        point.push( coord[1], coord[0]);
        coords.push( point );
    }
    var test = L.polygon( coords).addTo(map);
};


     
        
    }
};
```

The following console logs holds the data as asked in ajax, *console.log(response);* : only one polygon is asked each time..

```
Object { type: "FeatureCollection", features: (1) […] }
​
features: Array [ {…} ]
​​
0: Object { type: "Feature", id: 0, properties: {…}, … }
​​​
geometry: Object { type: "Polygon", coordinates: (1) […] }
​​​​
coordinates: Array [ (7) […] ]
​​​​​
0: Array(7) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], … ]
​​​​​​
0: Array [ -13.206044, 55.765013 ]
​​​​​​
1: Array [ -11.229188, 55.715583 ]
​​​​​​
2: Array [ -9.999144, 54.979196 ]
​​​​​​
3: Array [ -11.207223, 55.167712 ]
​​​​​​
4: Array [ -12.634953, 55.01697 ]
​​​​​​
5: Array [ -13.337835, 55.079848 ]
​​​​​​
6: Array [ -13.206044, 55.765013 ]
​​​​​​
length: 7
​​​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​​​
length: 1
​​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​​
type: "Polygon"
```

and the error preventing the translation to  a L.Polygon;

> Uncaught TypeError: data is undefined

Comment: Can you add a sample from your GeoJSON (a feature or two)?

Comment: @TomazicM yes, only one feature is retrieved each time. Meanwhile... I've just been seeing that my read_one_polygon.php was looking inside the points of the database.. not the polygons ! so i've just updated the php and the screenshots....

Comment: Pictures are not of a much use. Please add a sample of your GeoJSON `data` as it is fed to `L.geoJson(data, ...` (a feature or two)  as a text.

Comment: @TomazicM i updated the code and the sample - i hope this is what you mean .. in fact, I now asked the console.log to get the full response to the ajax code - i can't ask directly the php file because there are some session variables that are required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name of `onEachFeature` GeoJSON layer option tells, it's called for each **single** feature when loading GeoJSON data. This means that `layer.features` does not exist at all, only `layer.feature`. But since one of the function parameters is also `feature`, you can directly use this one.

So relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function _onEachFeature_editpolygon(feature, layer) {
  drawnItems_editpolygon.addLayer(layer);

  var coords = [];
  for (var j = 0 ; j < (feature.geometry.coordinates[0].length - 1); j++) {
    var coord = feature.geometry.coordinates[0][j];
    var point = [];
    point.push( coord[1], coord[0]);
    coords.push(point);
  }
  var test = L.polygon(coords).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: I just implemented this solution, after a long time because my code is beginning to be very heavy, and found out that it works. Thanks