# Loading shapefiles, GeoJSON, KML and GPX giving properties only for shapefiles in Leaflet

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, geojson, kml, gpx

The following code allows for loading local shapefiles, GeoJSON, KML and GPX, but items properties are not the same. Only shapefiles will return its properties with a bindpopup of global properties.

```
// base leaflet

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

// declarations for handling resulting data

var geo2 = L.featureGroup({}, {
        onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
            var out = [];
            if (f.properties){
            for(var key in f.properties){
            out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
            }
            l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
            }
        }
    })
    // .bindPopup('Hello world!')
    // .on('click', function() { alert('Clicked on a group!'); })
    .addTo(map);

var geo = L.geoJson({
    features: []
}, {
    // onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
    //   var out = [];
    //    if (f.properties){
    //    for(var key in f.properties){
    //      out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
    //    }
    //    l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    //  }
    // }
});

var geojsono;
var loadedfile;

// hidden file input

let filesender = document.createElement('input');
filesender.setAttribute("type", "file");
filesender.setAttribute("id", "filesender");
filesender.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
filesender.setAttribute("accept", ".zip, .geojson, .json, .gpx, .kml, application/gpx+xml,application/gpx,application/json,application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml,application/vnd.google-earth.kml");

document.getElementById('map').appendChild(filesender);

 var btn_loadfile = L.easyButton('fa-folder', function(btn, map) {
    function_loadfile();
  }).addTo(map);

  function loadfile() {
    document.getElementById('filesender').click();
    filesender.onchange = () => {
        let file = filesender.files[0],
            name = file.name,
            ext = name.split('.').pop(),
            filename = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')) || name

        if (ext != 'zip') { //gpx, kml, geojson
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(file);
            reader.onload = L.Util.bind((f) => {
                let data = f.target.result,
                    geojsono = ['gpx', 'kml'].indexOf(ext) !== -1 ? toGeoJSON[ext](new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/xml")) : JSON.parse(data);
                loadedfile = L.geoJSON(geojsono);
                geo2.addLayer(loadedfile);
            })
        } else {
            var data;
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            reader.onload = L.Util.bind((f) => {
                data = f.target.result,
                    geojsono = ['zip'].indexOf(ext) !== -1 ? shp(data) : JSON.parse(data);
                //  geo.addData(geojsono.outcome);
            });
            reader.onloadend = L.Util.bind(() => {
                geo.addData(geojsono.outcome);
                geo2.addLayer(geo);

            });
        };
    };
  };
```

I would like that all other file type (GeoJSON, KML, GPX) behave the same as shapefile or the contrary; that at the end they have the same contents at the same place - so I can do aditional stuff: exports, and showing the bindPopup.

The name attribute for a shapefile in plain text is found in
`geo2._layers[651]._layers[650].feature.properties.name`

and for a geojson and presumably the others:
`geo2._layers[631]._layers[632].feature.properties.name`

I can't see a difference, but nor a result.

Comment: What about any feedback to answer of your previous question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467448/retrieve-geometry-from-geojson-to-l-polygon-in-leaflet?

Comment: @TomazicM sorry I felt lost in the big amount of stuff that I have to fix,but I'll be looking at that right away...

Comment: I'm still dealing with polygons and watching this too today

Comment: Without samples from your KML, GPX and GeoJSON files and code for your convert procedure `toGeoJSON` it's impossible to say why it does not work for you. Please edit your question and add missing info.